# Scalar Function SQL By Linq Vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net, linq

I have a Function in Sql For check if username and password is Correct return 1 or 0

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[checklogin](@user varchar(30),@pass varchar(30))
Returns  BIT  
AS 
BEGIN  
DECLARE @check as bit
if (SELECT count(*) from dbo.Users where dbo.USERS.user_name= @user and  dbo.USERS.user_password=@pass)=1
set @check = 1
else
set @check=0
Return @check
END
```

when call this function without Sql linq Return Real information
[image: When Run the code]

```
  Sub loginCheck(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal frm As Form)

        Using con As New SqlConnection(inform.connectionstring)//
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select dbo.checklogin('Manager','123');", con)
                Dim a As Boolean = CBool(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                If a Then
                    MsgBox("Success")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Failed")
                End If
            End Using

        End Using
    End Sub
```

but when i need using linq return false always

```
   Sub loginCheck(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal frm As Form)

        Using con As New SqlConnection(inform.connectionstring)
            con.Open()
            Dim dta As New DataAj
            Dim ab As Boolean = dta.checklogin(username, password).Value
            If ab Then
                MsgBox("Success")
            Else
                MsgBox("Failed")
            End If

        End Using
    End Sub
```

[image: Return False]

Comment: You may want to check into `If Exists` for you sql function. Count scans the entire table. If Exists will stop as soon as it finds a match so it will be faster.

Comment: Not sure what type `dta.checklogin` returns but it wouldn't hurt to try `CBool(dta.checklogin(username, password).Value)`

Comment: @Mary Nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple function can be used to get value from exactly one field one record query result

```
Public Function getDataScalar(ssql As String)
    openConnection()

    Try
        Dim q As New MySqlCommand

        q.Connection = db
        q.CommandText = ssql
        getDataScalar = q.ExecuteScalar

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

How to use it:

```
Dim userid as String = getDataScalar("select username from user where userid=99")
```

Variable 'username' would be filled with the value of field username as a result from that query.